# When will my app users get latest app update if I upload updated version now ? Does Google push updates to all users at once or slowly push updates?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-update-app

We uploaded latest version of our app a few days ago but a few of our known users were not able to see the option to update the app on Google Playstore. Can someone throw some light on how google pushes app updates on Google Playstore? Why some users recieve updates later than others ?

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, update information itself is delivered within 2~4 hours in average. But most of them will download update package when they are in WiFi connection *and* charging condition.

Overall, we expect at least 2 weeks to spread out the new version unless the app does not make update forecefully.